# If i am interested in existence as a philosophical concern, where should I start reading?

Tags: ontology

I find the study of existence is quite an interesting topic, since we are always going about our daily lives doing this and that, often taking everything around us for granted. But I want to know what all these things around us such as trees rocks, flowers, stars, buildings and really everything actually mean in terms of the nature of their existence. Furthermore, do man made things exist in the same way that natural things exist? Because they come into existence in different ways.

Comment: The questions about the nature of being constitute the part of metaphysics called ontology, you can do some initial reading in [SEP survey](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/#ProMetOldMet). Then try to make your question more specific, as it is it is too broad to answer here.

Comment: Yeah, this question has too broad of a history in philosophy to be answerable in its current form. You can revise it by reading more or having a much more pointed comparison, but it's hard to imagine a version of this question that doesn't have *many* answers over the course of philosophy's history.

Comment: "But I want to know what all these things around us such as trees rocks, flowers, stars, buildings and really everything actually mean in terms of the nature of their existence." -- Wouldn't that lead you to physics and the natural sciences?

Comment: FMunden: I think your questions at the end are good!  Also: @user4894 riffs off Quine: we don't need any First Philosophy (ontology) skip go, and go directly to science. Naturalism. PV22: good idea too, study BEING, instead of beings. NB so hint to Munden, getting a bit of a taste of the possible ends of First Philosophy may make the long slog from Thales forward more goal directed.

Comment: Also, man made things, even culture, etc. are somtimes referred to as "second nature", in contrast to the nature we normally think of. I think this term originated with Hegel, but I'm not sure of it.

Comment: @PV22 I want to make clear I was referring to the second part of PV22's answer in my comment above, where he references Heidegger. Good idea, but as he suggested, difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend find a course on the subject.

> What do all these things around us such as trees rocks, flowers, stars, buildings and really everything actually mean in terms of the nature of their existence?

- Start with Socrates, Plato and Aristotle and work you way forward in time to Rene Descartes, Immanuel Kant... no simple task, especially without discussion and guidance. Each Philosopher also their own corpus, engaging multiple philosophical topics, so the name alone would probably not be enough guidance.

> Do man made things exist in the same way that natural things exist?

I would point to "Being and Time" by Martin Heidegger and other continental philosophers. Fair warning, it's dense.